# i am trying to create a simple live wallpaper with draw path but it doesnt work for me

Tags: android

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    int x, y;
    Canvas c;
    Rect dest;
    Paint paint;
    private Path m_Path;
    ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();
    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 6;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyWallpaperEngine();
    }


class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
    };
    private boolean visible = true;
    public Bitmap image1, backgroundImage;

    MyWallpaperEngine() {
        // get the fish and background image references
        image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.fish);
        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.back);
        x = -130; // initialize x position
        y = 200; // initialize y position

    }

    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visible = visible;
            // if screen wallpaper is visible then draw the image otherwise do
            // not draw
            if (visible) {
                handler.post(drawRunner);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TODO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            touch_start(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//              Toast.makeText(null, "TODO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                touch_move(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//              Toast.makeText(null, "TODO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                touch_up();

                break;
            }



        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
            }
        }


        private void touch_up() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            m_Path.lineTo(mX, mY);

            // commit the path to our offscreen
            c.drawPath(m_Path, paint);

            // kill this so we don't double draw
            m_Path = new Path();
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));


        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));


        m_Path.reset();
        m_Path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                m_Path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            this.visible = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }

        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
                float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            draw();
        }

        void draw() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                // clear the canvas
                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                ((WindowManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                if (c != null) {
                    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                    c.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, null, dest, paint);

                    Rect im = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
                    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                    c.drawBitmap(image1, null, im, paint1);


                    int width1 = c.getWidth();

                    // if x crosses the width means x has reached to right edge
                    if (x > width1 + 100) {
                        // assign initial value to start with
                        x = -130;
                    }
                    // change the x position/value by 1 pixel
                    x = x + 1;

                }

            }



            finally {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

            }

            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            if (visible) {
                handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10); // delay 10 mileseconds

            }



        }

    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-06 09:35:34.613: I/dalvikvm(8774): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
06-06 09:35:34.636: E/Trace(8774): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-06 09:35:39.730: D/AndroidRuntime(8774): Shutting down VM
06-06 09:35:39.730: W/dalvikvm(8774): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f172a0)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at com.sabeel.livewallpaper.MyWallpaperService$MyWallpaperEngine.touch_start(MyWallpaperService.java:159)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at com.sabeel.livewallpaper.MyWallpaperService$MyWallpaperEngine.onTouchEvent(MyWallpaperService.java:101)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1102)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
06-06 09:35:39.730: E/AndroidRuntime(8774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`m_Path` is **null** in inside `touch_start()` method try to initialize it like below and use it.

```
m_Path = new Path();
```